The label of the table is not correctly referring the actual table in the report
The following code shows that the table is labelled as Table4 . And also \autoref{Table4} is used in the paragraph. But it is referring the Table 3 in the report. How to solve this problem? How can my report refers the correct table in the paragraph?
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}

% amsmath and amssymb packages, useful for mathematical formulas and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Use adjustwidth environment to exceed column width (see example table in text)
\usepackage{changepage}

% Use Unicode characters when possible
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% textcomp package and marvosym package for additional characters
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}

% cite package, to clean up citations in the main text. Do not remove.
\usepackage{cite}

% Use nameref to cite supporting information files (see Supporting Information section for more info)
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}

% line numbers
\usepackage[right]{lineno}

% ligatures disabled
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }

% color can be used to apply background shading to table cells only
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% array package and thick rules for tables
\usepackage{array}

% create "+" rule type for thick vertical lines
\newcolumntype{+}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

% create \thickcline for thick horizontal lines of variable length
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\thickcline[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
  \cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}%
}

% \thickhline command for thick horizontal lines that span the table
\newcommand\thickhline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}


% Remove comment for double spacing
%\usepackage{setspace} 
%\doublespacing

% Text layout
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

% Bold the 'Figure #' in the caption and separate it from the title/caption with a period
% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}

% Use the PLoS provided BiBTeX style
\bibliographystyle{plos2015}

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother



% Header and Footer with logo
\usepackage{lastpage,fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\setlength{\headheight}{27.023pt}
%\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{PLOS-submission.eps}}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 2pt \vspace{2mm}}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{2.25in}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{2.25in}
\lfoot{\today}

%% Include all macros below

\newcommand{\lorem}{{\bf LOREM}}
\newcommand{\ipsum}{{\bf IPSUM}}

%% END MACROS SECTION


\begin{document}
\LTcapwidth=0.85\textwidth
\begin{longtable}{l|c|c|c}
\caption{\bf Results of multinomial logistic regression model for high life satisfaction compared to low life satisfaction showing relative risk ratios (RRR), 95\% confidence interval (CI) and p-values.}
\label{Table4}\\
\hline
 \textbf{Variables} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{95\% CI}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{p-value}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{\bf Table 4. (Continued)}\\
\hline
 \textbf{Variables} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{95\% CI}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{p-value}} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
%\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Low \\ satisfaction\end{tabular}} & (Base outcome) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
 \textbf{Intercept} & 0.308 & (0.242,0.391) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country} &  &  &  \\ 
  Bangladesh & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Nepal & 12.033 & (9.672,14.971) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan & 5.914 & (5.460,6.406) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Area} &  &  &  \\ 
  Urban & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Rural & 1.357 & (1.300,1.416) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Age} &  &  &  \\ 
  15-19 & 1 & - & - \\ 
  20-24 & 0.911 & (0.851,0.975) & 0.007 \\ 
  25-29 & 0.762 & (0.709,0.818) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  30-34 & 0.662 & (0.615,0.713) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  35-39 & 0.658 & (0.610,0.709) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  40-44 & 0.721 & (0.666,0.781) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  45-49 & 0.837 & (0.769,0.910) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Ever attended school} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 0.645 & (0.619,0.673) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Broadcast media\\ engagements\end{tabular}} &  &  &  \\ 
  Not using & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Partially using & 1.429 & (1.377,1.483) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Using almost everyday & 1.697 & (0.918,3.138) & 0.091 \\ \hline
  \textbf{ICT exposure} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ \hline
  No & 0.864 & (0.814,0.917) & \textless{}0.05 \\  \hline
  \textbf{Own a mobile phone} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 0.875 & (0.842,0.909) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Functional difficulty} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 2.128 & (1.961,2.308) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Marital status} &  &  &  \\ 
  Currently married & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Formerly married & 0.139 & (0.123,0.159) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Never married & 0.779 & (0.704,0.862) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Wealth index quintile} &  &  &  \\ 
  Poorest & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Second & 1.539 & (1.411,1.677) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Middle & 2.960 & (2.712,3.232) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Fourth & 4.409 & (4.030,4.824) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Richest & 8.644 & (7.817,9.558) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country-Wealth index} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
  Nepal-second & 1.404 & (1.017,1.937) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Nepal-middle & 0.734 & (0.534,1.009) & 0.057 \\ 
  Nepal-fourth & 0.731 & (0.521,1.024) & 0.068 \\ 
  Nepal-richest & 3.462 & (1.652,7.255) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-second & 0.894 & (0.806,0.992) & 0.036 \\ 
  Pakistan-middle & 0.662 & (0.595,0.737) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-fourth & 0.634 & (0.567,0.708) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-richest & 0.407 & (0.362,0.458) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country-Marital status} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
  Nepal-formerly married & 0.811 & (0.498,1.318) & 0.398 \\ 
  Nepal-never married & 0.611 & (0.439,0.849) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-formerly married & 1.096 & (0.928,1.296) & 0.279 \\ 
  Pakistan-never married & 1.011 & (0.907,1.128) & 0.835 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


Welcome. // Unfortunately your posted code doesn't and can't compile: verify yourself via a new file. // Resolving references usually requires 2 compiles ...

I have edited my code. The problem is that I am labelling the above table as Table4. Although I use \autoref{Table4} in the paragraph , it is referring it's previous table. I have 3 other tables in my report.

it is bad practice to use numbers in labels, as it can confuse you, as the label is just an internal identifier. clearly in the document posted the table is table 1 although it has label Table4

unrelated to your question, but don't use \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} in latex, it either gives a warning that it is doing nothing, or if you force it to load it will break latex's unicode support, also don't use \bf it is not defined by default in latex.

In the shown example, the table is “Table 1” and if I add a reference “See table~\ref{Table4}.” this is printed as “See table 1.“ and therefore is correct. So please show a minimal working example, that can be used to reproduce your issue, instead of an example, that does not show the issue.

BTW: You should not use manually added tale numbers like in \caption*{\bf Table 4 (Continue)}. Also readers are not interested in the number while reading the table, but what it shows. The number is needed only for references. So it would be better to use something like \caption[]{Results of multinomial … (Continue)}. And to configure caption to be bold, you should use package caption, which you are already loading. Please read the manual.

I would like to suggest that you replace
\caption*{\bf Table 4. (Continued)}\\

in the \endhead code block with
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries Table \thetable. (continued)}\\[0.5ex]

After making this change (as well as running \setcounter{table}{3} immediately after \begin{document}), the header of the longtable environment's second page will be as follows:

\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}

% amsmath and amssymb packages, useful for mathematical formulas and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Use adjustwidth environment to exceed column width (see example table in text)
\usepackage{changepage}

% Use Unicode characters when possible
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % better: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %%% new

% textcomp package and marvosym package for additional characters
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}

% cite package, to clean up citations in the main text. Do not remove.
\usepackage{cite}

% Use nameref to cite supporting information files (see Supporting Information section for more info)
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref} %%% no need to load 'hyperref' twice

% line numbers
\usepackage[right]{lineno}

% f-ligatures disabled
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }

% color can be used to apply background shading to table cells only
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% array package and thick rules for tables
\usepackage{array} %%% for '\newcolumntype' macro
% create "+" rule type for thick vertical lines
\newcolumntype{+}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

% create \thickcline for thick horizontal lines of variable length
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\thickcline[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
  \cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}%
}

% \thickhline command for thick horizontal lines that span the table
\newcommand\thickhline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}


% Remove comments for double spacing
%\usepackage{setspace} 
%\doublespacing

% Text layout
\raggedright %%% do you really want to disable all hyphenation?
   %%% If not, consider running '\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}' instead
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

% Bold the 'Figure #' in the caption and separate it from the title/caption with a period
% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,
   justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}

% Use the PLoS provided BiBTeX style
\bibliographystyle{plos2015}

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad #1.}
\makeatother



% Header and Footer with logo
\usepackage{lastpage,fancyhdr,graphicx}
%%%\usepackage{epstopdf}. %%% not needed (since 'graphicx' is loaded)
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\setlength{\headheight}{27.023pt}
%\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{PLOS-submission.eps}}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 2pt \vspace{2mm}}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{2.25in}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{2.25in}
\lfoot{\today}

%% Include all macros below

\newcommand{\lorem}{{\bf LOREM}}
\newcommand{\ipsum}{{\bf IPSUM}}

%% END MACROS SECTION

\captionsetup{font=bf}  %%% new



\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{3} % just for this example

\LTcapwidth=0.85\textwidth
\begin{longtable}{l|c|c|c}

\caption{Results of multinomial logistic regression model for high life satisfaction compared to low life satisfaction showing relative risk ratios (RRR), 95\% confidence interval (CI) and p-values.}
\label{Table4}\\
\hline
 \textbf{Variables} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)\end{tabular}}} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{95\% CI}} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{p-value}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries Table \thetable. (continued)}\\[0.5ex]
\hline
 \textbf{Variables} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{95\% CI}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{p-value}} \\ \hline
\endhead


%\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Low \\ satisfaction\end{tabular}} & (Base outcome) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
 \textbf{Intercept} & 0.308 & (0.242,0.391) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country} &  &  &  \\ 
  Bangladesh & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Nepal & 12.033 & (9.672,14.971) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan & 5.914 & (5.460,6.406) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Area} &  &  &  \\ 
  Urban & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Rural & 1.357 & (1.300,1.416) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Age} &  &  &  \\ 
  15-19 & 1 & - & - \\ 
  20-24 & 0.911 & (0.851,0.975) & 0.007 \\ 
  25-29 & 0.762 & (0.709,0.818) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  30-34 & 0.662 & (0.615,0.713) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  35-39 & 0.658 & (0.610,0.709) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  40-44 & 0.721 & (0.666,0.781) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  45-49 & 0.837 & (0.769,0.910) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Ever attended school} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 0.645 & (0.619,0.673) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Broadcast media\\ engagements\end{tabular}} &  &  &  \\ 
  Not using & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Partially using & 1.429 & (1.377,1.483) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Using almost everyday & 1.697 & (0.918,3.138) & 0.091 \\ \hline
  \textbf{ICT exposure} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ \hline
  No & 0.864 & (0.814,0.917) & \textless{}0.05 \\  \hline
  \textbf{Own a mobile phone} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 0.875 & (0.842,0.909) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Functional difficulty} &  &  &  \\ 
  Yes & 1 & - & - \\ 
  No & 2.128 & (1.961,2.308) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Marital status} &  &  &  \\ 
  Currently married & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Formerly married & 0.139 & (0.123,0.159) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Never married & 0.779 & (0.704,0.862) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Wealth index quintile} &  &  &  \\ 
  Poorest & 1 & - & - \\ 
  Second & 1.539 & (1.411,1.677) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Middle & 2.960 & (2.712,3.232) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Fourth & 4.409 & (4.030,4.824) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Richest & 8.644 & (7.817,9.558) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country-Wealth index} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
  Nepal-second & 1.404 & (1.017,1.937) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Nepal-middle & 0.734 & (0.534,1.009) & 0.057 \\ 
  Nepal-fourth & 0.731 & (0.521,1.024) & 0.068 \\ 
  Nepal-richest & 3.462 & (1.652,7.255) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-second & 0.894 & (0.806,0.992) & 0.036 \\ 
  Pakistan-middle & 0.662 & (0.595,0.737) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-fourth & 0.634 & (0.567,0.708) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-richest & 0.407 & (0.362,0.458) & \textless{}0.05 \\ \hline
  \textbf{Country-Marital status} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
  Nepal-formerly married & 0.811 & (0.498,1.318) & 0.398 \\ 
  Nepal-never married & 0.611 & (0.439,0.849) & \textless{}0.05 \\ 
  Pakistan-formerly married & 1.096 & (0.928,1.296) & 0.279 \\ 
  Pakistan-never married & 1.011 & (0.907,1.128) & 0.835 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


It is not entirely clear what is your problem. Therefore I only can  suggest some table adjustment which to my opinion make tabel nicer looking:

In MWE (Minimal Working Example) below I are used S of siunitx package columns types, for caption style is defined by caption package options, define is new command for writing table sections titles and for their inserting in table is added new column:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[font=small,
            textfont=bf, 
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}           % new
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{#1}}} % for table subtitles
\usepackage{makecell}                        % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}% new
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}


\begin{document}

See table~\ref{Table4}

\LTcapwidth=0.85\textwidth
\begin{longtable}{l   % added for inserting subtitles for table sections 
                  l|S[table-format=2.3]|c|
                    S[table-format=<2.3,
                      table-align-comparator = false]}
\caption{Results of multinomial logistic regression model for high life satisfaction compared to low life satisfaction showing relative risk ratios (RRR), 95\% confidence interval (CI) and p-values.}
\label{Table4}\\
    \hline
    &   \thead{Variables} & {\thead{Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)}} & \thead{95\% CI} & {\thead{p-value}} \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Table 4. (Continued)}\\
\hline
    &  \thead{Variables} & {\thead{Relative Risk\\ Ratio (RRR)}} & \thead{95\% CI} & {\thead{p-value}} \\ 
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\itshape Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\mcbf{Intercept}    & 0.308     & (0.242,0.391)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Country}                  &                   &       \\ 
    & Bangladesh    & 1         & -                 & {--}  \\ 
    & Nepal         & 12.033    & (9.672,14.971)    & <0.05 \\ 
    & Pakistan      & 5.914     & (5.460,6.406)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Area}         &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Urban         & 1         & --                & {--}  \\ 
    & Rural         & 1.357     & (1.300,1.416)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Age}          &           &                   &       \\ 
    & 15-19         & 1         & --                & {--}  \\ 
    & 20-24         & 0.911     & (0.851,0.975)     & 0.007 \\ 
    & 25-29         & 0.762     & (0.709,0.818)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & 30-34         & 0.662     & (0.615,0.713)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & 35-39         & 0.658     & (0.610,0.709)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & 40-44         & 0.721     & (0.666,0.781)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & 45-49         & 0.837     & (0.769,0.910)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Ever attended school}           
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Yes           & 1         & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & No            & 0.645     & (0.619,0.673)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{\thead[lt]{Broadcast media\\ engagements}} 
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Not using     & 1         & --                & {--}  \\ 
    & Partially using & 1.429   & (1.377,1.483)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Using almost everyday 
                    & 1.697     & (0.918,3.138)     & 0.091 \\ \hline
\mcbf{ICT exposure}  
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Yes           & 1         & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & No            & 0.864     & (0.814,0.917)     & <0.05 \\  \hline
\mcbf{Own a mobile phone}                   &   &   &       \\ 
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Yes           & 1         & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & No            & 0.875     & (0.842,0.909)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Functional difficulty} 
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Yes           & 1         & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & No            & 2.128     & (1.961,2.308)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Marital status}  
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Currently married & 1     & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & Formerly married  & 0.139 & (0.123,0.159)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Never married & 0.779     & (0.704,0.862)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Wealth index quintile} 
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Poorest       & 1         & {--}              & {--}  \\ 
    & Second        & 1.539     & (1.411,1.677)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Middle        & 2.960     & (2.712,3.232)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Fourth        & 4.409     & (4.030,4.824)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Richest       & 8.644     & (7.817,9.558)     & <0.05 \\ 
    \hline
\mcbf{Country-Wealth index}      
                    &           &                   &       \\* 
    & Nepal-second  & 1.404     & (1.017,1.937)     & <0.05 \\
    & Nepal-middle  & 0.734     & (0.534,1.009)     & 0.057 \\ 
    & Nepal-fourth  & 0.731     & (0.521,1.024)     & 0.068 \\ 
    & Nepal-richest & 3.462     & (1.652,7.255)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Pakistan-second & 0.894   & (0.806,0.992)     & 0.036 \\ 
    & Pakistan-middle & 0.662   & (0.595,0.737)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Pakistan-fourth & 0.634   & (0.567,0.708)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Pakistan-richest & 0.407  & (0.362,0.458)     & <0.05 \\ \hline
\mcbf{Country-Marital status}  
                    &           &                   &       \\ 
    & Nepal-formerly married 
                & 0.811     & (0.498,1.318)     & 0.398 \\ 
    & Nepal-never married 
                & 0.611     & (0.439,0.849)     & <0.05 \\ 
    & Pakistan-formerly married 
                & 1.096     & (0.928,1.296)     & 0.279 \\ 
    & Pakistan-never married 
                & 1.011     & (0.907,1.128)     & 0.835 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

See table~\ref{Table4}

\end{document}

